# Toggling Graphical Points on Mouse Click

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I am making a program where one can click on the window, and a point will be placed there. If the user clicks again, the point will be removed. Programmatically, each click will create a new instance of another class called "Element", which contains the (X, Y) positions for a single point.

To achieve this, I am extending JPanel and implementing a MouseListener. To draw the points,  I'm overriding the paint() method. Every time a user clicks, code the MouseListener's mouseReleased() either adds to the ArrayList, or removes from it, then calls paint(), where the screen is cleared and the ArrayList is redrawn.

The problem I am having is that the points aren't going away when clicked on. I don't know if it's my lack of understanding of paint(), or something to do with the ArrayList.

Here is my paint():

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // Clear screen
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    // Display what elements will be drawn (for debugging)
    System.out.println("About to draw the following elements:");
    for (Element e : elements)
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + e);
    }

    // Draw Elements
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i=0; i < elements.size(); i++)
    {
        g.fillOval(elements.get(i).x, elements.get(i).y, 10, 10);
    }

}
```

And here is the mouse click method:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    // Rounds to the nearest grid space (spacing is currently 20px)
    int roundX = (int) ((float)(Math.round(e.getX() / GRID_SPACING)) * GRID_SPACING);
    int roundY = (int) ((float)(Math.round(e.getY() / GRID_SPACING)) * GRID_SPACING);

    System.out.println("Clicked (" + roundX + ", " + roundY + ")");

    // Go through each element...
    for (int i=0; i < elements.size(); i++)
    {
        // if an element exists at the coordinates clicked,
        if (elements.get(i).getX() == roundX && elements.get(i).getY() == roundY)
        {
            // remove it from the elements list
            elements.remove(i);
            i--;
            System.out.println("\tElement exists at (" + roundX + ", " + roundY + "). Removing it.");
        }
    }

    elements.add(new Element(roundX, roundY));

    repaint();
}
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
  About to draw the following elements: (None)

Clicked (140, 100)
About to draw the following elements:
    This element's coordinates are (140, 100)

Clicked (160, 100)
About to draw the following elements:
    This element's coordinates are (140, 100)
    This element's coordinates are (160, 100)

Clicked (140, 100)
    Element exists at (140, 100). Removing it.
About to draw the following elements:
    This element's coordinates are (160, 100)
    This element's coordinates are (140, 100)
```

Comment: In your `mouseReleased` method you always do an `add`, even if you just removed an element. So even if you remove it, it will still be painted since you just added another element at the same location

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not `add(new Element(roundX, roundY))` if the element has been removed in the previous loop

Comment: Oh wow, how stupid of me! I'll blame it on it being so late in the day. Works great now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't override `paint(Graphics)` in a Swing panel.  Use `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead.

Comment: Why? Don't you think you should add an explanation of why to do that, especially since that's not going to fix the problem he asked about?